# Predicting order of nucleophilic substitution reactivity

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, reactivity

> 1. What order of reactivity do you predict will be observed when each alkyl halide is mixed with sodium iodide in acetone?
>
>    - 1-Chlorobutane
>    - 1-Bromobutane
>    - 2-Chloro-2-methylpropane
>    - Bromobenzene
>    - 2-Chlorobutane
>    - 1-Chloro-2-butene

I know that $\ce{I-}$ is the best leaving group, followed by $\ce{Br-}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$.
For the $\ce{NaI}$ reaction, tertiary halides should react fastest and primary halides should react slowest.

> 2. What order of reactivity do you predict will b observed when each alkyl halide is mixed with silver nitrate in ethanol?
>
>    - 1-Chlorobutane
>    - 1-Bromobutane
>    - 2-Chloro-2-methylpropane
>    - Bromobenzene
>    - 2-Chlorobutane
>    - 1-Chloro-2-butene

For the $\ce{AgNO3}$ reaction, primary halides should react fastest and tertiary halides should react slowest.

Which takes preference, leaving group or rank? Also, how do I rank 1-chlorobutane vs. 1-chloro-2-butene? They are both primary and the halide is $\ce{Cl-}$ for both.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27734/nucleophilic-substitution-reactions

Comment: Question one is basically which one does Sn1 fastest (aprotic solvent and strong nucleophile). So in question 1 you're looking for the least substituted species with the best leaving group. Question 2 is basically which one does Sn2 fastest (protic solvent and weak nucleophile). More subbed and better LG.

Comment: For the Chlorobutane/ene situation think about resonance stabilization in the intermediate/transition state.

Answer (score 1):

1. Acetone a is aprotic polar solvent which is often used as solvent for $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reactions (notably in conjunction with $\ce{NaI}$ as in the [Finkelstein reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finkelstein_reaction)). For $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reactions steric hindrance and leaving group capability is of great importance, so primary halides will be usually easier replaced by iodine then tertiary.
2. $\ce{AgNO3}$ will probably react as a base forming nitric acid. Even though nitric acid is a rather strong acid this is more likely than $\ce{NO_3-}$ acting as nucleophile. Besides that, $\ce{Ag+}$ is known to have a unique selectivity for halogens and will attack them readily, forming $\ce{AgX}$ and a carbocation, hence promoting $\ce{E 1}$/$\ce{S_{N}1}$.